# How can I access a member variable of the current running Activity in Android?

Tags: android, variables, android-activity

I have an Android activity running with a custom view in it.  When something happens within that custom view, I want to tell the currently running activity by changing one of the Activity member variables.  **Is there a way to access the current running activity member variables from within a custom view class besides passing the activity into the view class though a function arg?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, [`getContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()) in a `View` will return the `Activity` that created the `View`.

Comment: When I'm inside the view and I call getContext() and cast it to an Activity variable, the IntelliSense doesn't let me access any of my custom methods or member variables.  Eclipse also won't let me compile if I try to reference any of those activity member vars or functions because it doesn't know about them before the code is run :S

Comment: Your custom variables aren't members of `Activity`. You should cast the `Context` to `YourActivity`, not just `Activity`